# Transitioning Karma Test Running From Terminal to PHPStorm / WebStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I am currently running Karma in the background in a Terminal instance.  I would like to incorporate Karma into my instance of PHPStorm going forward.  I've been watching this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyWW_V4wALs) and read through this [tutorial](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Running+JavaScript+tests+with+Karma).  Both of them assume that a 'karma.conf.js' has not been created and guides you through the process of setting them up.  I already have an existing 'karma.conf.js' file and would like to start running tests using that file.

I am assuming I would need to go to 'Run' -> 'Edit Configurations' to get the testing coverage set up.  But there doesn't seem to be an option in the 'Edit Configurations' screen that let's you choose Karma.  Is there documentation somewhere that goes over how to start using an existing Karma config file in PHPStorm / Webstorm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What PHPStorm version do you work with? Note that you need to install karma plugin in order to use the integration - this plugin is not bundled with PHPStorm. In Settings/Plugins press `Browse Repositories..` and enter 'karma' in the search box to quickly locate the plugin. When it's installed, karma run configuration can be created from the right-click menu of 'karma.conf.js' or using Edit Configurations dialog

Comment: The official tutorail video didn't mention the plug-in so I was under the impression Karma came built-in with the default PHPStorm installation.  Added the repo through PHPStorm and everything is churning as expected